# Можно ли сказать «действующие члены академии»?

Tags: паронимы

Точно можно говорить *действительный член*, а можно ли говорить *действующий*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно так говорить, но эти выражения не синонимичны. **Действующий** означает нынешний, работающий. А **действительный** — это звание (статус).

Рассмотрим на примере РАН: действительный член РАН — то же, что *академик РАН*; действующий член РАН — ныне работающий академик, член-корреспондент или иностранный член РАН.